# why Partial function in scala is giving run time error for input 0?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am expecting my partial function to discard for input 0 , but instead it is giving match error . Will you please explain exactly why is it happening? What I am missing?
[image]

```
object PartialFunction extends App {

  val divider : PartialFunction[Int,Int] = {
    case d : Int if d != 0 => 42/d
  }
  println(divider(0))
  //println(fraction(0))
}
```

Comment: because it can't match any of your patterns?

Comment: What is your expected output? How could the compiler know what to do with that `divider(0)` call? You should wrap it with a `if (divider.isDefinedAt(0))`

Answer (score 3):

You did not tell what to do when the input is 0. 0 does not match the case where because of the guard `d != 0`

Change your implementation to accommodate `0` case

```
  val divider : PartialFunction[Int,Int] = {
    case d : Int if d != 0 => 42/d
    case 0 => 0 //return some integer
  }
```

Comment: Thank you , I was thinking as case is matching for any integer , why it shows match error for 0 , but yeah now I am pretty clear , it's guard which is preventing to evaluate 0, so it's kind of nomatch for 0 .

Answer (score 1):

Or you can define what's the default case.

```
val divider : PartialFunction[Int,Int] = {
    case d : Int if d != 0 => 42/d
    case _ => 0
  }
```